# Combination or permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Now I know the formal definitions of permutation and combination  and also know that forder means arrangement of things while the latter implies selection of things. However , I have been facing this problem of trying to determine from the given  problems as to whether it is a combination problem or a permutation problem along with identifying as to Wether the question is related to mutually exclusive events or not . Is there a way to do away with this confusion  ?

Comment: Can you explain what the "girls end problem" is?

Comment: Oh sorry this darn self injecting grammar thing in my phone, edited now.Thanks

Comment: @user366398 That doesn't really help; examples of problems would help show us what's confusing you.

Comment: No problem.  I think, though, your question is too general to admit a useful answer.  In each case, start by enumeration. Even if it's clear that there are far too many to actually list, start writing down some admissible solutions.  Does the order matter or not?  If, say, I ask you for the probability of getting dealt a full house,  I think you'd agree that $\{K\spadesuit, K\heartsuit, K\clubsuit, 4\diamondsuit, 4\clubsuit\}$ was the same hand as $\{4\clubsuit\,K\spadesuit,K\clubsuit,4\diamondsuit,K\heartsuit\}$...so this would be a "combinations problem".

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments mention, every problem is different and therefore no blanket piece of advice will provide a universal approach to each problem.

That being said, it can really help your understanding of combinations and permutations if you enhance your understanding of *sets* and *lists*. Here is a great primer for becoming proficient at counting problems and some great practice problems: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/Discrete/ChapterCounting.pdf

Unfortunately, the only way to better recognize permutations, combinations, and mutual exclusivity (or a combination of two or more of these mathematical constructs within the same problem) is through practice, lots of it.

When you hit a particularly difficult problem or need help, get help from someone, or come back to Stack Exchange and ask for help! I'm sure someone will be happy to help you dissect the problem and clarify points of confusion for you.